# How can we pass multiple values to an attribute in Graphical mapping

Tags: mapping, user-defined-functions, sap-pi

​During message mapping I faced a problem where I need to assign values to a node basing on the values of attribute assigned to it (which are constants). How can I map the attribute with multiple values
[image: Graphical Mapping]

I don't know how to achieve this in graphical mapping . the Target xml at Value node should look like this

```
<Values>
      <Value AID ="Account">123456</Value>

       <Value AID = "Type" ID="S">name </Value>

</Values>
```

where 123456(Account) will be assigned dynamically and name is always constant .attribute ID has to be disabled when Value node is assigned with Account .I believe we can map  "Value" node basing on value assigned to attribute AID. Can someone provide a solution to achieve this in graphical mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by duplicating the subtree and mapping the values to attributes in duplicated subtree.